# Security Help? Is this a safe way of doing things?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, debian

I am running Apache with Debian. At the moment to share my site I am just setting up my router to foward my local ip on port 80.  So anyone who wanted to look at my site can just type in my router's ip.

Is this a safe way of doing things?

Comment: [Practice safe computing.](http://drtech.bangordailynews.com/files/2014/02/condom-ethernet.jpg)

Comment: @HopelessN00b lmao

Comment: Publicly available servers are generally firewalled off from sensitive data via [a DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)). If you have sensitive data on your server or elsewhere on the same network, you probably shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a safe way of doing things?

How confident are you that your application doesn't have any massive security vulnerabilities?

(that's answering a question with another question, but you get the point.)

Answer (score 0):

EEAA is correct. It *can* be a safe way of doing it if you are confident that your web-app or site, your Debian implementation, and your Apache implementation are secure.

This is essentially how a web-app or website is served from a DMZ to the Internet: only the necessary port(s) -- tcp/80, tcp/443, etc. -- are opened between the router/firewall/perimeter device and the webserver, so external traffic can only reach the port specified.

So the answer is, "Maybe".